# cyclic dependency node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node JS documention on Cyclic module dependencies

> When main.js loads a.js, then a.js in turn loads b.js. At that point,
>   b.js tries to load a.js. In order to prevent an infinite loop, an
>   unfinished copy of the a.js exports object is returned to the b.js
>   module. b.js then finishes loading, and its exports object is provided
>   to the a.js module.

I don't understand the above statement, specially returning the unfinished copy which mean that at times it can result in undefined behavior.

Does this mean that we should always avoid cyclic dependency in Node to avoid undefined behavior? Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that you should always avoid them, but it means you should strive to avoid them. The same documentation says _"Careful planning is required to allow cyclic module dependencies to work correctly within an application."_ I'm not sure what is the typical approach to dealing with this, but one option would be to have an asynchronous polling loop check whether the properties of the modules have finished loading.

Comment: @JLRishe can you please give an code example of "asynchronous polling loop for properties"?

Comment: `const handle = setInterval(() => { if (a.somePropertyThatShouldBeDefined) { clearInterval(handle); startTheAction(); } }, 100);`